# Estimating the parameter of a Gaussian Copula

Tags: correlation, fitting, copula

Consider the problem where I want to fit a bivariate Gaussian copula to two sets of observations. Call the observations:

$$ \big\{(x_i, y_i)\big\}_{i=1,...,n} $$

For a Gaussian copula there is one parameter to estimate, $\rho$.

My question is: can I use the (Pearson) correlation coefficient of the samples as my estimated parameter, $\hat{\rho}$? Or is the correlation completely unrelated to what is meant by $\rho$?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you assuming a bivariate Gaussian distribution (Gaussian marginal distributions)?

Comment: Isn't that parameter *defined* as the correlation coefficient of the original (untransformed) bivariate Gaussian distribution?

Comment: @Dave I'm not making any assumptions about the marginals? Do I need to?

Comment: @whuber It is if the original bivariate distribution is Gaussian. I've played with the `copula` package in R and used exponential marginals with a Gaussian copula, and the copula parameter is not the same (in expectation) as the correlation coefficient I get. Maybe that has to do with bias in estimating the correlation in R's `cor` function with the non-Gaussian marginal distributions, but from what I recall, the graphs sure didn't make it look like a linear relationship.

Comment: @Dave Thank you for that clarification: I misread this question as assuming the univariate distributions are Gaussian.  When they are not, $\rho$ may deviate substantially from their correlation.  This becomes clear when you contemplate two marginal distributions that do not have the same shape (they aren't affinely related), for then correlation coefficients close to $1$ are mathematically impossible. I know this issue is addressed in other threads here -- somewhere.

Comment: Closely related questions can be found at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=gaussian%20copula%20correlation%20answers%3a1